# How can i catch the Playsound()'s return value and do someting else if it doesn't find the .wav

Tags: c, return-value, playsound

My problem is the following. I play sounds with the Playsound() function without problem, but if the program can't find the suitable sound file (because it doesn't exist) i want to print "The file is not exis" sencence instead of the program play the default "bip" voice. Is there any way to get a value if the Playsound()'s play is not success. Theoretically it returns TRUE if successful or FALSE otherwise but I can't catch non of them with a variable.
I programing in C and use DevC++ 4.9.9.2 and CodeBlocks 12.11 without any success.

Thanks any help!

```
My Codes:

//Try_1:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
main()
{
//if (!PlaySound("R2D2.wav",NULL, SND_FILENAME )) // not working
if (!PlaySound("R2D2.wav",NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_NODEFAULT | SND_ASYNC)) // not working properly
    {
        printf("The file is not exist");
    }

system("pause");
}
/*
If the program can't find the R2D2.wav then there isn't the default "bip" voice thanks to the SND_NODEFAULT, but the printf line will not run so I don't see the "The file is not exist" sentence.
*/
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
//Try_2:
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
main()
{
//Returns TRUE if successful or FALSE otherwise.
bool x;
x=PlaySound("R2D2.wav",NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_NODEFAULT | SND_ASYNC); // not working properly
    if (x==FALSE)
    {
        printf("The file is not exist");
    }
system("pause");
}
/*
If the program can't find the R2D2.wav then there isn't the default "bip" voice thanks to the SND_NODEFAULT, but the printf line will not run, so I don't see the "The file is not exist" sentence.
*/
```

Comment: Write a function about checking if a file or path exists first, then do what you like base on the existing or not: `if(isFileExists("media/audio/R2D2.wav"))`.

Comment: Thanks the idea Frederick, you are a hero!
I write a code but i can't post now because i have less than 10 reputation, however it is working perfectly.
But what is delayed may happen later, so if i won't forget i put it up tomarrow.

Answer (score 0):

This code is check the file. If it exist, than play the sound. If not, print a message.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

int isFileExists(char *filename);

main()
{
int b=9;
char *p,Array[9];

strcpy(Array,"R2D2.wav");
p = Array;
b=isFileExists(p);
    if(b==21)
    {
        PlaySound("R2D2.wav",NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_NODEFAULT | SND_ASYNC);
    }
    else if (b==20)
    {
            printf("The file is not exist");
    }


system("pause");
}

int isFileExists(char *filename)
{
FILE *file;
file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        return 20; //The file is not exist
    }
fclose(file);
return 21; //The file is exist
}
```